# React Error: Cannot update during an existing state transition

Tags: reactjs, onclick, ecmascript-6

I have the following click handler:

```
<Select
    name="batchCompChooser"
    value={this.state.batchCompId}
    options={batchCompItems}
    clearable={false}
    onChange={this.handleBatchCompChange()}
    />
```

However, I get the following error from the onChange line:

```
BatchComponentChooser.js?0aaf:54 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: This is not a question/answer.. This just seems like an answer to a non-question. Consider instead asking a question and answering it yourself.

Comment: Asking a question and answering it is allowed, but that's not what you did here.

Comment: Okay I will reformat, thanks.  Still learning the ropes at stack overflow.  After years of taking information, trying to give some back...

Comment: Changed this to question and answer format.

Comment: Trying my best to make this into a proper format.  This has been reworded to exactly the issue that caused me to post a question in the first place.  Please take off hold as I think allot of newcomers to react could benefit from the discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an event handlers, such as onClick, it is easy to accidentally do this:

```
onClick={this.someFunc()}
```

**REMOVE THE parens ()**

That will actually invoke the function immediately on render.

Instead you want to pass a reference to a function like this:

```
onClick={this.someFunc}
```

So in my case it should look like this:

```
<a onClick={this.doSomething}>Do something link</a>
```

If you need to pass parameters, you can do it like this with the arrow function:

```
<a onClick={() =>this.doSomething(true)}>Do something link</a>
```

Specifically in the example above the onChange should have the trailing parens removed, it should be changed to:

```
<Select
  name="batchCompChooser"
  value={this.state.batchCompId}
  options={batchCompItems}
  clearable={false}
  onChange={this.handleBatchCompChange}
/>
```

Hope that helps someone out there...

Comment: updated answer to address reworded question